# Why does ReactDOM.render() return null in useEffect with state as dependency?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-dom

If checked through the two methods of EventListener, ReactDOM.render() in the code below is returning null. Why is that?
(React version: 17.0.2)

The first method is a nested structure with a keyboard state as a dependency in useEffect. In this way, ReactDOM.render() returns null.
However, Test components are rendered properly on the screen.

The second method used eventListener directly inside the useEffect. This method does not return null by ReactDOM.render().

```
// index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="home"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// App.js
function App() {
  //
  const [element, setElement] = useState(null);

  // Error code
  const [keyboard, setKeyboard] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (keyboard === "KeyS") {
      const elementDiv = createElement(Test);
      const test = ReactDOM.render(elementDiv, document.getElementById("home"));
      console.log(test);
      // return null
      setElement(test);
    }
  }, [keyboard]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const createKeyEvent = (e) => {
      setKeyboard(e.code);
    };
    const removeKeyEvent = () => {
      setKeyboard(null);
    };

    document.addEventListener("keydown", createKeyEvent);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", removeKeyEvent);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", createKeyEvent);
      document.removeEventListener("keyup", removeKeyEvent);
    };
  }, []);

  // correct code
  useEffect(() => {
    const createKeyEvent = (e) => {
      if (e.code === "KeyS") {
        const elementDiv = createElement(Test);
        const test = ReactDOM.render(
          elementDiv,
          document.getElementById("home")
        );
        console.log(test);
        // return correct
        setElement(test);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("keydown", createKeyEvent);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", createKeyEvent);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">hi</div>;
}

export default App;
```

```
// Test.js

export default class Test extends Component {
  //
  render() {
    return <div>hello</div>;
  }
}
```